# Displaying String on a UI Label

Tags: ios, xcode6

I am new to Swift and not great in Obj-C either. I am trying to display a message to a UILabel but having a tough time with this.

I force downcast a "AnyObject" to NSString which gets the html data from a webpage (stored in the url variable). I split this object into a two element array where the seperation string is given in the code.

I then further split the 2nd element of the array into 2 elements and I now want to display the 1st element of this latest array on the UILabel (called "message").

Here is my code for this:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var textField: UITextField!

    var city: String = "city" // just a dummy initialization   
    var web: String = "http://www.weather-forecast.com/locations/"   

    @IBOutlet weak var message: UILabel! 
    @IBAction func getWeather(sender: AnyObject) {         
        city = textField.text;
        city.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString(" ", withString: "")
        city = city + "/forecasts/latest"
        web = web + city;

        var url = NSURL(string: web)
       // println(url)

        let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(url!){ (data, response, error) in

            var content = NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding);
            var splitArray = content?.componentsSeparatedByString("<span class=\"phrase\">");

            content = (splitArray![1]) as? NSString
            splitArray = content?.componentsSeparatedByString("</span>") 
            var weather = splitArray![1] as String
            message.text = weather;        
        }
        task.resume();
    }
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.   
    }   
    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
}
```

I am getting an error in the last line `message.text = weather` and the error message says `Reference to property'message' in closure requires explicit 'self'. to make capture semantics explicit`.

Can anyone please help describe what this error message means? Adding 'self' before 'message' doesn't display the required string in the label either.

Thanks!

Comment: `message` isn't defined anywhere in the posted code, so its hard to tell a) just what the problem is and b) what you "want this app to do".

Comment: What happens if you change the name of the weather field?

Comment: Hello Scott and Daniel, thanks for your responses and I have edited my post to show the complete code. I'm just starting out on coding so excuse my coding inefficiencies.
Changing the weather field resulted in the same error.

Comment: Hi, the code works for me now. Had to force my _weather_ variable to be of String type and downcast _splitArray_ from NSString to String.

Updated piece of code:

var weather: String  = splitArray![0] as String;
            
self.message.text = weather;